# add content other than attribute information under “Additional information” in magento

Tags: magento, tabs

we can see "Additional information " tab in magento product view page.

there we can list all attributes.

I want to display some contents under "Additional information " tab....

means

Main information

attribute label 1 : attribute value

Sub - information

attribute label 2 : atribute value.

please let me know if you need any clarifications.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please explain which attributes are under Main information and which are under Sub - information.

Comment: it's not like main information and sub information, i want to add texts in middle of 

attributes.....

Comment: under additional information,

color: green

weight : 250

Main features :

price : 150

cost :100

sku : sku1

i want to add " Main features: " text between "weight" and "price" attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered on [Magento SE](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/58303/243):

> You could customize the template
>   `catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml`. Copy it to your theme from
>   `base/default` if it isn't there yet and include what you need.
>
> For better maintainability, I'd recommend to just add
>   `$this->getChildHtml('my_child_alias')` to the template and define
>   child blocks in the layout (i.e. `layout/local.xml` of your theme:
>
> ```
> <reference name="product.attributes">
>     <block type="core/template" name="my.custom.product.block" as="my_child_alias" template="my/custom/template.phtml" />
> </reference>
> ```

Judging by the additional information from your comments here, you probably don't want to create child blocks, instead you'll have to add code within the `foreach` loop.

### Original

```
    <?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
        <tr>
            <th class="label"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
            <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

### Changed (example)

```
    <?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
        <?php if ($_data['code'] == 'attribute_1'): ?>
        <tr><th colspan="2"><?php echo $this->__('Main Information') ?></th></tr>
        <?php elseif ($_data['code'] == 'attribute_2'): ?>
        <tr><th colspan="2"><?php echo $this->__('Sub Information') ?></th></tr>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <tr>
            <th class="label"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
            <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

where `attribute_1` and `attribute_2` are the codes of the first attributes of each group.

Answer (score 0):

Modify File : **catalog\product\view\attributes.phtml.**

Replace `<th></th>` by this code.

```
<th class="label">
<?php if(array_key_exists('size',$_additional) && array_key_exists('color',$_additional) ){
                        if($_data['code'] == 'size'){
                            echo " Main features : ";
                        }
                    } ?>
                    <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->__($_data['label'])) ?>
                </th>
```

Apply this code and check out put.